# How to explicitly set parameter type for NuSOAP in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

When making a SOAP call with NuSOAP, I'm getting the SOAP fault:

***No deserializer for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType***

The request looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:impl="http://rtw.dncrtelem" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <impl:WashNumbers xmlns:impl="http://rtw.dncrtelem">
      <TelemarketerId xsi:type="xsd:string">****</TelemarketerId>
      <WashOnlyUserId xsi:type="xsd:string">****</WashOnlyUserId>
      <TelemarketerPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">****</TelemarketerPassword>
      <ClientReferenceId xsi:type="xsd:string">****</ClientReferenceId>
      <NumbersToWash xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:anyType[2]">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:anyType">1234567890</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:anyType">0987654321</item>
      </NumbersToWash>
    </impl:WashNumbers>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I paste the request into soapUI and change the type of "item" from "xsd:anyType" to "xsd:string", then it works fine.
e.g.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:impl="http://rtw.dncrtelem" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <impl:WashNumbers xmlns:impl="http://rtw.dncrtelem">
      <TelemarketerId xsi:type="xsd:string">****</TelemarketerId>
      <WashOnlyUserId xsi:type="xsd:string">****</WashOnlyUserId>
      <TelemarketerPassword xsi:type="xsd:string">****</TelemarketerPassword>
      <ClientReferenceId xsi:type="xsd:string">****</ClientReferenceId>
      <NumbersToWash xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:anyType[2]">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">1234567890</item>
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">0987654321</item>
      </NumbersToWash>
    </impl:WashNumbers>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I explicitly set the type for that when constructing my SOAP call? Have searched but can't seem to find the solution.

Here's my PHP code:

```
include_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$client = new nusoap_client('https://www.donotcall.gov.au/dncrtelem/rtw/washing.cfc?wsdl', 'wsdl');

$err = $client->getError();
if($err){
    // Error handling here
} else {
    $client->setUseCurl(true);
    $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
    $params = array('TelemarketerId'=>'****', 'WashOnlyUserId'=>'****', 'TelemarketerPassword'=>'****', 'ClientReferenceId'=>'****', 'NumbersToWash'=>array('1234567890','0987654321'));
    $result = $client->call('WashNumbers', $params);

    if ($client->fault) {
        // Fault handling here
    } else {
        $err = $client->getError();     
        if ($err) {
            // Error handling here
        } else {
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using "soapval", code change as follows:

```
$numbers = array('1234567890','0987654321');
$sv1 = array();
foreach ($numbers as $index => $number) {
    $sv1[] = new soapval('Number', 'xsd:string', $number);
}
$params = array('TelemarketerId'=>'****', 'WashOnlyUserId'=>'****', 'TelemarketerPassword'=>'****', 'ClientReferenceId'=>'****', 'NumbersToWash'=>$sv1);
```

Comment: What is `soapval` ? Do you mean [`SoapVar`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php) ?